# Why no error about undefined variable is raised in LISP while setq()?

Tags: emacs, lisp

In my Emacs config I have such a string:

```
(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
  (quote (("default"
           ("dired"
            (mode . dired-mode))
           ("System"
            (or (name . "\*scratch\*")
                (name . "\*Messages\*")))
           ("SVN"
            (name . "^\\*vc-.*\\*$"))))))
```

The variables `name` and `mode` are undefined but the code is evaluated correctly.  When I try to make a such on my own:

```
(some-var . "some-value")
```

I receive an error about the undefined variable `some-var`.

Comment: [Read about quoting](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) in the emacs manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a datum is quoted, nothing within is evaluated. For example:

```
foo
```

evaluates to the value bound to the identifier `foo`, whereas

```
'foo
```

or

```
(quote foo)
```

evaluates to the symbol `foo`.

Likewise,

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

evaluates to 6, whereas

```
'(+ 1 2 3)
```

or

```
(quote (+ 1 2 3))
```

evaluate to a list with four elements: the symbol `+`, and the numbers 1, 2, and 3. In particular, the `+` is not evaluated.

Similarly, your `name` and `mode`, both being within the quoted datum, are not treated as identifiers, but as symbols. They are not evaluated.

Comment: Exactly! For no reason I thought before that (quote) there quotes top level list only not variables.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's because name and mode are in (quote            )

Answer (score 0):

Look at C-h v ibuffer-saved-filter-groups. It explains about this variables further.  It is an alist variable. According to documents, it should look like (("STRING" QUALIFIERS) ("STRING" QUALIFIERS) ...)   Now QUALIFIERS is a LIST of the same form as `ibuffer-filtering-qualifiers'. It is a LIST like  (SYMBOL . QUALIFIER).